# At change of kunnr delete lines or proceed

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I have an itab which has the fields kunnr, bukrs, prodgrp & amound.
I have the below lines:

```
150 1000 adsl  10
150 1000 adsl1 15
150 1000 adsl2 20
150 8000 vdsl  25
150 8000 vdsl1 10
200 1000 adsl1 80
200 1000 adsl2 80
```

I want to do the following: 
At the end of each customer sum the amount and if it is less than the amount that put the user in selection screen, delete the lines of itab. If it is bigger leave them. This itab at the end of the program will be displayed.
Any idea on how to do it in a quick way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a write-my-code-for-me service.

Comment: **TL; DR**: use `AT NEW...END AT` for this task. Your title explicitly suggest this construct.

Comment: Try to use on change of "the_field ... endon inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting in the current itab, I would use a new itab and only add the aggregations that match your condition.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458368/make-math-operations-on-a-grouped-table/39470752#39470752) showing how to aggregate your data in a new itab, and use your user input threshold (pa_user_threshold) before the append.

```
IF pa_user_threshold >= lf_sum.
   APPEND ls_agg TO lt_agged.
ENDIF.
```