# Filter out records within z table according to the newest record

Tags: abap

I'm using ztable that has list of employees inside table, each employee has unique ID `pernr`, however each change in database is reflected with duplicated IDs, therefore the table looks like this:

| pernr | sname | begindate | enddate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 | 1.1.2000 | 1.1.2010 |
| 1 | Name1 | 2.1.2010 | 1.1.2015 |
| 1 | Name1 | 2.1.2015 | 31.12.9999 |
| 2 | Name2 | 1.1.2016 | 1.1.2019 |
| 2 | Name2 | 2.1.2019 | 31.12.9999 |

```
FORM process_data.
   DATA: lt_ztable   TYPE TABLE OF ztable,
   ls_ztable         LIKE LINE OF lt_ztable,
   ls_salv_table     LIKE LINE OF gt_salv_table.

   SELECT pernr, sname, begindate, enddate
   FROM ztable
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ztable.

   LOOP AT lt_ztable INTO ls_ztable
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING ls_ztable to ls_salv_table.
      APPEND ls_salv_table TO gt_salv_table.
   ENDLOOP.
ENDFORM.
```

What I need, is to filter out the data from ztable and display it as ALV `cl_salv_table` through the `gt_salv_table` however, only one record, the one with greatest difference between dates(so the ones ending with year 9999).

I was thinking do it within the SQL code, creating `begindate, enddate AS datediff`, though I didn't know how to formulate the `WHERE` statement that would filter only the records
with greatest difference. Or would it be better to filter it out in the `LOOP AT` part?
Thanks for any idea.

Comment: The greatest difference between the dates will always be the entry with enddate = 31.12.9999, won't it be? In this case the cindition WHERE enddate EQ '99991231' in the SELECT statement will do it. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Forgot to mention, it's not really a sure thing, that the date would be 31.12.9999, unfortunately the table has dates like 31.12.2099 as well...

Comment: From your example it would be enough to go with MAX(enddate) to get the latest entry. If the table can also hold entries with validity in the future, add the condition begindate <= sy-datlo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping + aggregation of itab with table comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640273/grouping-aggregation-of-itab-with-table-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by selecting data into internal table sorted with enddate in descending order and then delete the duplicates comparing pernr.

```
FORM process_data.

   SELECT pernr, sname, begindate, enddate
     FROM ztable
     INTO TABLE gt_salv_table
     **ORDER BY pernr ASCENDING enddate DESCENDING.**
   IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
     DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM gt_salv_table COMPARING pernr.
   ENDIF.

ENDFORM.
```

As futu suggested, MAX(enddate) can also be used, but you wont be able to select begindate in the aggregate query as the GROUP BY clause will need all not aggregated fields. If the business logic permits you could use MAX(begindate) and MAX(enddate) both to get all the data. Here, assumption is the name will be same for all records.

```
   SELECT pernr, sname, MAX(begindate) AS begindate, MAX(enddate) AS enddate
     FROM ztable
     INTO TABLE @gt_salv_table
     GROUP BY pernr, sname.
```