# ABAP - Group employees by cost center and calculate sum

Tags: loops, group-by, abap, collect

I have an internal table with employees. Each employee is assigned to a cost center. In another column is the salary. I want to group the employees by cost center and get the total salary per cost center. How can I do it?

At first I have grouped them as follows:

```
Loop at itab assigning field-symbol(<c>) 
group by <c>-kostl ascending.

Write: / <c>-kostl.
```

This gives me a list of all cost-centers. In the next step I would like to calculate the sum of the salaries per cost center (the sum for all employees with the same cost-center).

How can I do it? Can I use collect?

Update:
I have tried with the follwing coding. But I get the error *"The syntax for a method specification is "objref->method" or "class=>method""*. `lv_sum_salary = sum( <p>-salary )`.

```
loop at i_download ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<c>)
    GROUP BY <c>-kostl ascending.
    Write: / <c>-kostl, <c>-salary.

    data: lv_sum_salary type p DECIMALS 2.
    Loop at group <c> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<p>).
    lv_sum_salary = sum( <p>-salary ).
     Write: /'  ',<p>-pernr,  <p>-salary.
    endloop.
     Write: /'  ', lv_sum_salary.
  endloop.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping + aggregation of itab with table comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640273/grouping-aggregation-of-itab-with-table-comprehensions)

Comment: @Suncatcher Thanks for your help. I have tried to update my coding. But I get a dump. Any idea? thanks a lot!

Comment: @Poseidon what dump did you get? Can you provide us with the error message?

Comment: @schmelto If I try to active the code I get the message "The syntax for a method specification is "objref->method" or "class=>method". This error occours in the line -> lv_sum_tant = sum( <p>-tant ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, to group and sum, there are these 4 possibilities (code snippets provided below):

1. [SQL with an internal table as source: `SELECT ... SUM( ... ) ... FROM @itab ... GROUP BY ...`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect_itab.htm) (since ABAP 7.52, HANA database only); NB: beware the possible performance overhead.
2. The classic way, everything coded:

   - Sort by cost center
   - Loop at the lines

     - At each line, add the salary to the total
     - If the cost center is different in the next line, process the total
3. [LOOP AT with GROUP BY, and LOOP AT GROUP](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abaploop_at_itab_group_by.htm)
4. [VALUE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_value.htm) with [FOR GROUPS and GROUP BY](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfor_groups_of.htm), and [REDUCE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_reduce.htm) and [FOR ... IN GROUP](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenfor_in_group.htm) for the sum

Note that only the option with the explicit sorting will sort by cost center, the other ones won't provide a result sorted by cost center.

All the below examples have in common these declarative and initialization parts:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_itab_line,
         kostl  TYPE c LENGTH 10,
         pernr  TYPE c LENGTH 10,
         salary TYPE p LENGTH 8 DECIMALS 2,
       END OF ty_itab_line,
       tt_itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_itab_line WITH EMPTY KEY,
       BEGIN OF ty_total_salaries_by_kostl,
         kostl          TYPE c LENGTH 10,
         total_salaries TYPE p LENGTH 10 DECIMALS 2,
       END OF ty_total_salaries_by_kostl,
       tt_total_salaries_by_kostl TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_total_salaries_by_kostl WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA(itab) = VALUE tt_itab( ( kostl = 'CC1' pernr = 'E1' salary = '4000.00' )
                            ( kostl = 'CC1' pernr = 'E2' salary = '3100.00' )
                            ( kostl = 'CC2' pernr = 'E3' salary = '2500.00' ) ).
DATA(total_salaries_by_kostl) = VALUE tt_total_salaries_by_kostl( ).
```

and the expected result will be:

```
ASSERT total_salaries_by_kostl = VALUE tt_total_salaries_by_kostl(
    ( kostl = 'CC1' total_salaries = '7100.00' )
    ( kostl = 'CC2' total_salaries = '2500.00' ) ).
```

Examples for each possibility:

1. SQL on internal table:

   ```
   SELECT kostl, SUM( salary ) AS total_salaries
     FROM @itab AS itab ##DB_FEATURE_MODE[ITABS_IN_FROM_CLAUSE]
     GROUP BY kostl
     INTO TABLE @total_salaries_by_kostl.
   ```
2. Classic way:

   ```
   SORT itab BY kostl.
   DATA(next_line) = VALUE ty_ref_itab_line( ).
   DATA(total_line) = VALUE ty_total_salaries_by_kostl( ).
   LOOP AT itab REFERENCE INTO DATA(line).
     DATA(next_kostl) = VALUE #( itab[ sy-tabix + 1 ]-kostl OPTIONAL ).
     total_line-total_salaries = total_line-total_salaries + line->salary.
     IF next_kostl <> line->kostl.
       total_line-kostl = line->kostl.
       APPEND total_line TO total_salaries_by_kostl.
       CLEAR total_line.
     ENDIF.
   ENDLOOP.
   ```

   EDIT: I don't talk about [`AT NEW` and `AT END OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapat_itab.htm) because I'm not fan of them, as they don't explicitly define the possible multiple fields, they implicitly consider all the fields before the mentioned field + this field included. I also ignore [`ON CHANGE OF`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapon.htm), this one being obsolete.
3. LOOP AT with GROUP BY:

   ```
   LOOP AT itab REFERENCE INTO DATA(line)
       GROUP BY ( kostl = line->kostl )
       REFERENCE INTO DATA(kostl_group).
     DATA(total_line) = VALUE ty_total_salaries_by_kostl(
         kostl = kostl_group->kostl ).
     LOOP AT GROUP kostl_group REFERENCE INTO line.
       total_line-total_salaries = total_line-total_salaries + line->salary.
     ENDLOOP.
     APPEND total_line TO total_salaries_by_kostl.
   ENDLOOP.
   ```
4. VALUE with FOR and GROUP BY, and REDUCE for the sum:

   ```
   total_salaries_by_kostl = VALUE #(
       FOR GROUPS <kostl_group> OF <line> IN itab
       GROUP BY ( kostl = <line>-kostl )
       ( kostl          = <kostl_group>-kostl
         total_salaries = REDUCE #( INIT sum = 0
                                    FOR <line_2> IN GROUP <kostl_group>
                                    NEXT sum = sum + <line_2>-salary ) ) ).
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot four your really good explanation! This helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where you got the `sum` function from, but there is no such build-in function. If you want to calculate a sum in a group-by loop, then you have to do it yourself.

```
" make sure the sum is reset to 0 for each group
CLEAR lv_sum_salary.
" Do a loop over the members of this group
LOOP AT GROUP <c> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<p>).
  " Add the salary of the current group-member to the sum
  lv_sum_salary = lv_sum_salary + <p>-salary.
ENDLOOP.
" Now we have the sum of all members
WRITE |The sum of cost center { <c>-kostl } is { lv_sum_salary }.|.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply. Your code working well.